# How to fix text that is not visible in react-native app

Tags: react-native, components

I'm facing an issue with react-native.
It is working correctly on the simulator and iPhone7, but it isn't working on iPhone XR.
I'm not sure if this happens for all iPhone XR.
[image]
[image]

The first one is from iPhone XR and the second one is from the simulator.

[image]

As you can see here, I'm able to select text and clear text, just they are not visible.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

It looks like the text has a white color.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you have dark mode enabled, which can cause the text in a `<TextInput/>` to show up blank (this is a React Native issue).  Adding `color: '#000000'` to the text input styles should fix it.

Comment: Could you provide a link to that issue?

Comment: Ah, in Expo my setting was set to dark mode - I updated to "ios.userInterfaceStyle=dark" in app.json thank you!